# using 'flat' shader interfacce variables causes massive drop in performance

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, glsles, webgl2

When working on optimizing our WebGL2 rendering engine, I tried specifying some of the variables in the shader interfaces (between fragment and vertex shaders) as 'flat'. These variables can indeed be treated as flat and are essentially uniform for the entire rendered geometry. (but they are loaded in the vertex shader).

before:

```
in vec4 v_metadata;
in vec4 v_lightmapPatchCoords;
in vec4 v_matValue0;
in vec4 v_matValue1;
in vec3 v_viewPos;
in vec3 v_worldPos;
in vec3 v_viewNormal;
in vec2 v_textureCoord;
in vec2 v_vertexCoords;
in vec2 v_trimPatchCoords;
```

after:

```
flat in vec4 v_metadata;
flat in vec4 v_lightmapPatchCoords;
flat in vec4 v_matValue0;
flat in vec4 v_matValue1;
in vec3 v_viewPos;
in vec3 v_worldPos;
in vec3 v_viewNormal;
in vec2 v_textureCoord;
in vec2 v_vertexCoords;
in vec2 v_trimPatchCoords;
```

However, this simple change causes a massive drop in performance. my renderer goes from 50fps down to ~20fps on the same data.
Its difficult to find information on shader interfaces and how they can impact performance. I would expect 'flat' variables to be more efficient than smooth.

I know I am passing a lot of data between the vertex and fragment shaders and believe that this may be a bottleneck in the rendering, but its difficult to confirm this.

I wonder if due to the ANGLE interface layer, the generated HLSL is somehow poorly generated causing a big difference in efficiency.

Comment: you can look at what angle generates with the `WEBGL_debug_shader` extension. You can also look at [ANGLE's source](https://github.com/google/angle)

Comment: no idea about perf but it looks clear from this code that flat support requires more work to emulate in D3D. https://github.com/google/angle/blob/0661eb899f46160fcf2e7edc74f1462863c7e07a/src/libANGLE/renderer/d3d/ProgramD3D.cpp#L599